# How do I remove a Data Extension linked to an attribute group?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, contactbuilder

I need to be able to delete Data Extension how ever it is linked to an attribute group:

> You cannot delete any data extensions with existing data relationships
>   before removing those relationships. Use Data Designer to remove those
>   relationships before attempting a deletion.

I can't see any option to delete just one attribute. Is there any option to be able to delete a data extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to unlink the data extension from the attribute group, which can be done using the following steps:

1. You need to go to *Audience Builder -> Contact Builder* (Data Designer with Attribute Groups view should be open now)
2. Select the attribute group your data extension is in
3. Click on the icon in the link from the contact key, etc. to your data extension
4. unlink the data extension by clicking on that same symbol in the opened dialog
5. Click the "Save"-button and your data extension is successfully unlinked from that attribute group
6. Now the data extension can be deleted

**Related documentation:**

- [Edit an Attribute Group](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/data_designer/edit_an_attribute_group/)

Comment: Note: You are unable to edit or delete "System-Defined" linked Data Extensions, even as Admin/MC admin.